# c# subtract duplicates in merge datatables

Tags: c#, .net, linq, merge, concatenation

Code:

```
// Datatable DB
DataTable CashBillingsArticles_DB = new DataTable();
var CashBillingsArticles_DB_Primary = CashBillingsArticles_DB.Columns.Add("article_id", typeof(Int32));
CashBillingsArticles_DB.Columns.Add("article_quantity", typeof(Double));
CashBillingsArticles_DB.Columns.Add("article_sellprice", typeof(Double));
CashBillingsArticles_DB.Columns.Add("article_discount", typeof(Double));
CashBillingsArticles_DB.Columns.Add("article_isv", typeof(Double));
CashBillingsArticles_DB.Columns.Add("article_total", typeof(Double));
CashBillingsArticles_DB.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { CashBillingsArticles_DB_Primary };

// DB Data
CashBillingsArticles_DB.Rows.Add(1, 1, 5, 0, 0, 5);
CashBillingsArticles_DB.Rows.Add(2, 2, 6, 0, 0, 12);
CashBillingsArticles_DB.Rows.Add(4, 1, 10, 0, 0, 10);
CashBillingsArticles_DB.Rows.Add(7, 2, 3, 0, 0.9, 6.9);

// DataTable Grid
DataTable CashBillingsArticles_Grid = new DataTable();
var CashBillingsArticles_Primary = CashBillingsArticles_Grid.Columns.Add("article_id", typeof(Int32));
CashBillingsArticles_Grid.Columns.Add("article_quantity", typeof(Double));
CashBillingsArticles_Grid.Columns.Add("article_sellprice", typeof(Double));
CashBillingsArticles_Grid.Columns.Add("article_discount", typeof(Double));
CashBillingsArticles_Grid.Columns.Add("article_isv", typeof(Double));
CashBillingsArticles_Grid.Columns.Add("article_total", typeof(Double));
CashBillingsArticles_Grid.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { CashBillingsArticles_Primary };

// Grid Data
CashBillingsArticles_Grid.Rows.Add(2, 1, 6, 0, 0, 6);
CashBillingsArticles_Grid.Rows.Add(3, 1, 1, 0, 0.15, 1.15);
CashBillingsArticles_Grid.Rows.Add(4, 3, 10, 0, 0, 30);
CashBillingsArticles_Grid.Rows.Add(7, 4, 3, 0, 1.8, 13.8);
```

I need to show this result comparing the article_id column in the tables and always show the article_sellprice value of the datatable CashBillingsArticles_Grid:

```
id qty price desc  isv   total
1  -1   5     0    0     -5
2  -1   6     0    0     -6
3   1   1     0    0.15   1.15
4   2  10     0    0      20
7   2   3     0    0.9    6.9
```

**Graphic Illustration:**
In the database i have:
[image]

The user make some modifications to the invoice and the final result is:
[image]

I need to get the differences between the database and the user grid modification, like this: (I need this output)

[image]

Comment: What did you actually get compared to what you want? Anything else to post?

Comment: I need to compared the pk `article_id` if the pk are equal in the datatables then subtract `article_quantity`, `article_discount`, `article_isv`, `article_total`...

Comment: "but i failed to get the desired result" I mean, what do you mean by "failed", and do you expect ("desired result" - give actual expectation) can you post it too?

Comment: Then use LINQ joins just like you'll do it in SQL. With linq I always write in in simple SQL then write that SQL to LINQ.